# how to fix background flickering when doing high frequency inserts at index 0 [ag-grid]

Tags: ag-grid

when I do high frequency inserts in ag-grid at index 0, the background of the rows starts flickering and then after some time its correct again.

```
                api.gridApi.applyTransaction({
                  add     : dataClone,
                  addIndex: 0
                })
```

I made a video of what I mean
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJGYub6mRAg

would appreciate any advice :)

edit: it seems to be a bug, I can reproduce it with one of their samples
https://plnkr.co/edit/kLUAwWYdled5uRsN?preview

created a github issue
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/5037

Comment: sorry no advice, but is this useful : https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3458  ?
does it only happen when inserting at index 0 ?

Comment: @clogwog, yes it only happens when I insert at the start, I dont think that github issue is quite the same